# How do I sandbox a JS lib?

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript lib and it seems to be failing because of my other libs on this big site. Is there a way I can sandbox it somehow? perhaps putting it in an iframe then assigning a var in my javascript class as

```
var myvar = iframe.theJSlib;
```

I'm just writing an idea. I don't know how to sandbox nor if it could be done. How do I sandbox a javascript lib and access it in my main page?

Answer (score 1):

This is why we practice keeping vars out of the global scope. Try to either enclose everything in the lib in its own function, like so:

```
(function(){
  // the library code
}());
```

Keep in mind this will only fix explicitly declared variables like `var foo = 'bar';` but will NOT fix implicitly declared variables like `foo = 'bar'`, which will still be assigned to the global object, most likely `window`.

You can also try to change all your code to use a single namespace like so:

```
var myApp = {};

myApp.foo = { /* maybe my validator code */ };
myApp.bar = { /* maybe my utilities code */ };
```

Comment: To avoid implicit globals, you can use the `"use strict";` directive. It won't prevent overwriting existing globals though.

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in an Iframe would certainly stop it from working properly. All you can do is wrap the offending code in a function so everything runs within the scope of that function.

See: [Javascript Namespacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684452/javascript-namespacing)

And: [JavaScript Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410984/javascript-namespace)

Comment: This won't necessarily work because it will still affect the window object unless you run them in compatibility mode

Comment: Yes, a lot of this depends on the behaviour of the script as well. Scripts deliberately polluting the global space are also likely to break things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just sandbox one lib at a time. 
You have to sandbox them all by running them in compatibility mode in their own namespaces:

```
(function(myLib){
    // do stuff with this lib here
})(theLongLibname)
```

Comment: This somehow didnt fix it. I don't exactly know whats going on. I suspect it may be using global names and not caring

Answer (score 0):

put it in an anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    // >Your code goes here<
})();
```